# Confirmation dialog on select box in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a select in my form where a user can select a brand and it will filter a list. I want to be able to show a confirmation dialog box before that list is filtered so if the user clicks the select box and picks item one, it will ask if they are sure they want to confirm, if they pick yes, it will filter the list and if they pick no, nothing will happen. I have the select box working but I am not sure on how to get a dialog box to show and action it when yes or no is clicked:

select box:

```
  <MudSelect @bind-Value="@selectedBrand" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled">
            @foreach (var item in brand) {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@item.Id">@item.Description</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a `ConfirmDialog` component:

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        @Message
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Message { get; set; }

    void Submit() => MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
    void Cancel() => MudDialog.Cancel();
}
```

Then handle the `ValueChanged` `EventCallback` of `MudSelect` component to show the dialog and change the selected value based on the dialog result:

```
@inject IDialogService DialogService

<MudSelect T="string" Label="Coffee" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter"
           Value="_selectedCoffee" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cappuccino")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cafe Latte")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Espresso")" />
</MudSelect>

<p>Selected coffee: @_selectedCoffee</p>

@code {
    private string _selectedCoffee;

    private async Task OnValueChanged(string value)
    {
        var parameters = new DialogParameters();
        parameters.Add("Message", $"Are you sure you want to apply filter: '{value}'?");

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<ConfirmDialog>("Confirm", parameters);

        var result = await dialog.Result;

        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {
            _selectedCoffee = value;
            // filter the list
        }
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYGmvOuSrKRPaAQS)

[Dialog documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog)